# getting Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY] while trying to install Layar401.apk

Tags: android

I have downloaded the `Layar401.apk` file from web and trying to install it into my android device (HTC Magic, Android 2.2). But every time I'm trying to install it its saying:

```
adb install Layar401.apk
1098 KB/s (1855698 bytes in 1.649s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Layar401.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]
```

From other posts I figured out that there might be a missing shared library of Google maps api in `manifest.xml` file. I tried to view the `manifest.xml` file and it gave me something like following:

```
package: name='com.layar' versionCode='27' versionName='4.0.1'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.CAMERA'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.VIBRATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
application: label='Layar' icon='res/drawable/icon.png'
uses-library:'com.google.android.maps'
launchable activity name='com.layar.Main'label='Layar' icon=''
sdkVersion:'3'
targetSdkVersion:'4'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.camera'
main
other-activities
other-receivers
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
locales: '--_--' 'ja' 'de' 'he' 'sk' 'el' 'nl' 'ko' 'fr' 'tr' 'es' 'it' 'pt' 'hu' 'ru' 'sv' 'fr_CA' 'zh_HK' 'zh_CN' 'pt_BR' 'es_US' 'zh_TW'
densities: '120' '160' '240'
```

But here it says library includes google maps api as well. So I'm not sure why I'm not able to install this apk file.

Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your device lacks the Google Maps API, apparently.

Comment: Any suggestion how to include that though?

Comment: @zeb: You would have to ask whoever gave you your ROM.

Comment: Well I'm not sure ... If it does not have Google Maps API how the map is running on the device?

Comment: @zeb: My best guess is that it's not in there quite right from the standpoint of non-firmware apps. Maps was on there when you installed the firmware, right? If the app works on a Maps-equipped emulator, and does not work on the device, the device is the source of your trouble.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party here but you may like to do this to add the Googlemaps API to your android after installing the maps apk.
http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/25334-fixing-the-install-failed-missing-shared-library-error/

Answer (score 0):

zeb,

Knowing that you use cyanogenmod 6.0, this might be useful to examine:

http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/5687-is-anyone-else-able-to-download-layar-places-directory-on-cm6/

Comment: Thanks Kanov ... I'll try to figure it out!